LaTeX/amsmath \prescript causing undefined control sequence
The following equation:
\begin{gather}
\prescript{A}{B}{R_\gamma} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \cos(\gamma) & -\sin(\gamma) \\
    0 & \sin(\gamma) & \cos(\gamma) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\prescript{A}{B}{R_\beta} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\beta) & 0 & \sin(\beta) \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -\sin(\beta) & 0 & \cos(\beta)
\end{bmatrix}
\prescript{A}{B}{R_\alpha} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 \\
    \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\prescript{A}{B}{R} =\prescript{A}{B}{R_\alpha}\prescript{A}{B}{R_\beta}\prescript{A}{B}{R_\gamma}
\\
\prescript{A}{B}{R} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) & \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma) - \sin(\alpha)\cos(\gamma) & \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma) + \sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma) \\
    \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) & \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma) + \cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma) & \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma) - \cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma) \\
    -\sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta)\sin(\gamma) & \cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)
\end{bmatrix}
\label{eq:rot}
\end{gather} 

which is displayed correctly with Overleaf´s preview hover box:

results in the following compilation errors and the \prescript tag ultimately gets ignored in the compiled version:

amsmath is being imported correctly with the \usepackage{amsmath} at the top of the document. What is causing this control sequence error?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

And now you know why we always ask for full minimal examples. There preamble (and class) is missing. See Davids answer. My crystal ball says the same.

Apologies for not including a full minimal example, it was an oversight on my part. Will do this moving forward!

amsmath does not define a command \prescript so an undefined command error is not unexpected. You have shown no relevant code but have you loaded mathtools ?
You are probably missing
\usepackage{mathtools}

in code not shown.

Ah yes, thank you. I mistakenly thought that \prescript was from amsmath, not mathtools. Once loaded, it compiled successfully.
